# AWS S3 bucket cross account policy mixed with internal account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

we use s3 bucket to share files between two companies. We created private S3 bucket and we have dedicated user for application which uses this bucket (using it's aws_key and aws_secret). We figured out that we don't have access to getObject, but we sucessfully PutObject to bucket.

Also I've created role with permissions to this bucket and assigned it to application_user, but it did not resolve the issue.

So main goal is to have read,list,put access from external account and internal IAM user to same S3 bucket. I will point that external company has access to it, right now with this policy.
I don't have access to external aws account.

Below there is a resource policy for s3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SharedS3Bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::199999999999:root",    <--- external account 
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/application_user" <-- our application user
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::shared-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::shared-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 permissions are a little complicated because you have not only the **Bucket permissions** to worry about but also each **Object** that you upload has its own permissions.

Your *Bucket Policy* above permits both companies to upload objects, and it works as you can see. However when the external company uploads an object it's default permissions *only allow reading by the creator*, i.e. by the external company. Even if it's in *your* bucket by default *you* can't read it if it was uploaded by someone else. That's somewhat counter-intuitive.

The solution is to make sure that the uploaded Objects have ACL that permits reading by both accounts.

[image: S3 Upload Dialog]

You will also need to add `s3:PutObjectAcl` to your list of Bucket Policy permissions for this to work.

Similarly if you're uploading from the command line you can modify the object acl after upload with `aws s3api put-object-acl`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and clear explanation. I appreciate it. This is exact answer for my question. Each object in s3 has own permissions and these permissions need to be granted even for bucket owner.